# In MS SQL Server Need to search multiple strings in a column and update another column in a table based on search

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In MS `SQL Server` Need to search multiple strings in a column and update column in a table

So Now I want to search records based on strings and update Category_1 column based on the result

```
SELECT *
FROM Consolidated
WHERE Group_By_Me LIKE '%Weld cap%'
      OR Group_By_Me LIKE '%C-Factor%';
```

Sample data

[image]

Comment: i didn't down vote.. but i do have no idea what you are trying to do. can you give example of the before and after view of all relevant tables maybe?

Comment: Think you need to use the LIKE operator, but we need more info in order to help you.

Comment: I used like operator but how to update entire table??

Comment: I mean can I use Loops in SQL

Comment: You can, but why would you?

Comment: But I have like 33 strings. Is it a good idea to use CASE??

Answer (score 0):

By design :)

```
UPDATE Consolidated
SET <another column> = CASE 
                          WHEN  Group_By_Me Like '%Weld cap%' THEN 'value1'
                          WHEN  Group_By_Me Like '%C-Factor%' THEN 'value2'
                       END
WHERE
   Group_By_Me Like '%Weld cap%' OR Group_By_Me Like '%C-Factor%'
```

Comment: Thank you. But how do I update entire table without writing multiple update statements?